# Passing an array to PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, plsql

I am trying to pass an array from a shell script to PL?SQL procedure.

```
    sqlplus -s $RAN_UID <<EOF > $OUTPUTS/$file.txt
    set serveroutput on;
    declare
        type nation_list is table of varchar2(100);
        v_nations nation_list := nation_list(${nation//,/','});
    begin
        for i in 1..v_nations.count loop
            dbms_output.put_line('Nation = ' || v_nations(i));
        end loop;
        process_failed_requests(p_nations => v_nations, p_lastrundate => '$LastRun');
    end;
    /
EOF
```

so here I am logging in to schema `$RAN_UID`. $nation has `'AA,AF,AG'` in it and I need to pass it to a PL/SQL procedure.

Below is my PL?SQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE process_failed_requests(p_nations IN VARCHAR2, p_lastrundate IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT B.CIDGEN, B.NATION
        FROM COMPANY B
        JOIN NATION_LOOKUP C ON B.NATION = C.CODE
        WHERE B.CIDGEN IN (
            SELECT CIDGEN
            FROM RAN.OA_REQUEST_RESPONSE_STATUS
            WHERE RESPONSE_STATUS = 'FailedRequest'
            AND RESPONSE_UPDATE_STAMP >= TO_DATE(p_lastrundate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        )
        AND B.NATION IN (SELECT regexp_substr(p_nations, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY regexp_substr(p_nations, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
    ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.CIDGEN || '||' || rec.NATION);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

However I am facing below issue:
`cat oa_req_failed_temp.txt process_failed_requests(p_nations => v_nations, p_lastrundate => '12-Feb-2024 04:36:33'); * ERROR at line 8: ORA-06550: line 8, column 9: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCESS_FAILED_REQUESTS' ORA-06550: line 8, column 9: PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

However it works fine when the parameters are directly passed in the PL/SQL procedure.

```
-- procedure process_failed_requests
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE process_failed_requests(p_nations IN VARCHAR2, p_lastrundate IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT B.CIDGEN, B.NATION
        FROM COMPANY B
        JOIN NATION_LOOKUP C ON B.NATION = C.CODE
        WHERE B.CIDGEN IN (
            SELECT CIDGEN
            FROM RAN.OA_REQUEST_RESPONSE_STATUS
            WHERE RESPONSE_STATUS = 'FailedRequest'
            AND RESPONSE_UPDATE_STAMP >= TO_DATE(p_lastrundate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        )
        AND B.NATION IN (SELECT regexp_substr(p_nations, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY regexp_substr(p_nations, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
    ) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.CIDGEN || '||' || rec.NATION);
    END LOOP;
END;
/

-- Test script
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    p_nations VARCHAR2(100) := 'AA,AF'; -- Example input: Comma-separated list of nations
    p_lastrundate VARCHAR2(20) := '01-JAN-2000 00:00:00'; -- Example input: Last run date
BEGIN
    process_failed_requests(p_nations, p_lastrundate);
END;
/
```

Comment: A POSIX shell does not have arrays. You can't pass something which does not exist. And even if you would use a shell which does support arrays (zsh for instance), there is - at least in the common operating systems (Linux, MacOS, ....) no standard way to pass an array from  a parent process to a child process. The only supported way for passing information is in form of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure has the signature:

```sql
PROCEDURE process_failed_requests(p_nations IN VARCHAR2, p_lastrundate IN VARCHAR2)
```

It works when you use:

```sql
DECLARE
    p_nations VARCHAR2(100) := 'AA,AF'; 
    p_lastrundate VARCHAR2(20) := '01-JAN-2000 00:00:00';
BEGIN
    process_failed_requests(p_nations, p_lastrundate);
END;
/
```

It does not work when you use:

```sql
declare
  type nation_list is table of varchar2(100);
  v_nations nation_list := nation_list(${nation//,/','});
begin
  process_failed_requests(p_nations => v_nations, p_lastrundate => '$LastRun');
end;
/
```

This is because `v_nations` is a (locally defined) `NATION_LIST` data-type and not a `VARCHAR2` and, exactly as the exception message states, the procedure call has the "wrong number or types of arguments" (in this case, types of arguments).

If "`$nation` has `'AA,AF,AG'` in it" then assign it to the correct type, `VARCHAR2`:

```sql
declare
  v_nations VARCHAR2(100) := ${nation};
begin
  process_failed_requests(p_nations => v_nations, p_lastrundate => '$LastRun');
end;
/
```